# Select dropdown onChange and ngModel issue

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular

I have a simple Angular 2 component which has a select dropdown having two-way binding with an object property and also a change event bound to a method that manipulates that object. 
Here is the component

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core'

@Component({
 selector: 'my-app',
 providers: [],
 template: `
  <div>
    <h2>Hello {{name}}</h2>

    <select (change)="save()" [(ngModel)]="testObject.selectVal">
      <option [selected]="testObject.selectVal=='Value 1'">Value 1</option>
      <option [selected]="testObject.selectVal=='Value 2'">Value 2</option>
      <option [selected]="testObject.selectVal=='Value 3'">Value 3</option>
    </select>

</div>
`,
directives: []
})
export class App {

 testObject:any;

 constructor() {
   this.name = 'Angular2 (Release Candidate!)'

   this.testObject = {
     selectVal : "Value 2"
   }

 }

 save(){

   alert(this.testObject.selectVal);

 }
}
```

When i change the select, it should alert the value of the current selected option but instead it always shows the last value of the select dropdown. I have a feeling that there is a race condition going on between the `ngModel` update and `change` trigger because i tried putting in a delay before the alert in `save` method and it seems to work fine.

To demonstrate it better i have setup a demo plnkr [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/C9lodyvqxp7ecXQgTVp4?p=preview).

Answer (score 2):

You don't need

```
[selected]="testObject.selectVal=='Value 1'"
```

The item is selected from the value `testObject.selectVal` passed to select by `[(ngModel)]`

If `testObject.selectVal` doesn't contain one of `Value 1`, `Value 2`, or `Value 3`, then use (for string values)

```
  <option [value]="someVal">Value 1</option>
```

or other values like object

```
  <option [ngValue]="someVal">Value 1</option>
```

Comment: Good point, but the main problem still persists. The value is still not updated on time.

Comment: Use `(ngModelChange)="save()"` instead

Comment: That does not help either

Comment: That's weird. I'd consider this a bug. What you can do is `(ngModelChange)="save($event)"` and use the passed (`$event`) value but with `(ngModelChange)="save()"` it should IMHO work the same.

Comment: This is a known bug with the `(change)` event, which oddly fires before  the `ngModel` gets updated. You even commented on it yourself, @GünterZöchbauer :D (https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/7971) - `ngModelChange` should work however.

Comment: @rinukkusu It's known, but I don't think it's a bug that `(change)` fires before `(ngModelChange)`. I also assumed `(ngModelChange)` to work, but it didn't in the Plunker. This is what I considered a bug.

Answer (score 0):

You can use as alternative since alert event fired first than the ngModelChange

```js
public save(item){
    alert(item);
  }
```

```html
<select (change)="save(item.value)" #item [(ngModel)]="testObject.selectVal">
      <option [selected]="testObject.selectVal=='Value 1'">Value 1</option>
      <option [selected]="testObject.selectVal=='Value 2'">Value 2</option>
      <option [selected]="testObject.selectVal=='Value 3'">Value 3</option>
    </select>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same race condition among the `(change)` handler and the model binding. Using `(ngModelChange)` solved it for me ([documentation link](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html#!#ngModel)).

Meaning, in your case:

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core'

@Component({
 selector: 'my-app',
 providers: [],
 template: `
  <div>
    <h2>Hello {{name}}</h2>

    <select (ngModelChange)="save()" [(ngModel)]="testObject.selectVal">
      <option [selected]="testObject.selectVal=='Value 1'">Value 1</option>
      <option [selected]="testObject.selectVal=='Value 2'">Value 2</option>
      <option [selected]="testObject.selectVal=='Value 3'">Value 3</option>
    </select>

</div>
`,
directives: []
})
export class App {

 testObject:any;

 constructor() {
   this.name = 'Angular2 (Release Candidate!)'

   this.testObject = {
     selectVal : "Value 2"
   }

 }

 save(){

   alert(this.testObject.selectVal);

 }
}
```

Hope this helps you.